Create video with a set of images with a mix of portrait and landscape ratio using ffmpeg
I wonder how can one create a video with a set of images with a mix of portrait and landscape ratio using ffmpeg.
For simplicity, let's say we have only two combinations of the dimension: 640x360 and 360x640. What I expect is to create a 640x640 video. When the frame is in the landscape ratio, create equal padding on the top and bottom. When the frame is in the portrait ratio, create equal padding on the left and right.

create list of images (file '1.jpg'...) and use pad → ffmpeg -r 1 -f concat -i list.txt -vf "pad='max(iw,ih)':'max(iw,ih)':-1:-1" out.mp4

In practice, you'll have to manually specify the sizes in pad e..g pad=640:640:-1:-1

@БаярГончикжапов It works. Thank you!
